# Why does echo "$@" not show the script name but explicit iteration does?

Tags: bash

Please consider the script `foo.bash`

```
#!/bin/env bash

echo "$@"
echo

for x in "${@:0:$# + 1}" ; do
    echo "$x"
done
```

Then `./foo.bash a b c` gives the output

```
a b c

./foo.bash
a
b
c
```

As far as I understand the documentation, `@` holds the positional arguments, so the output of `echo "$@"` makes sense to me.

But why does the `for` loop print the script name?

edit:

I'm using Git BASH on Windows, `echo $BASH_VERSION` yields 4.4.23(1)-release

Comment: I can't repro on Bash 3. I guess you have uncovered an implementation detail. In Bash 5 I can repro with `echo "${@:0}"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior is specific to `bash` ver 4+.

As per `man bash`

> `@`  Expands  to  the  positional  parameters,  starting  from one.  That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3"` ...

However:

> `${parameter:offset:length}`
> Substring Expansion.  Expands to up to length characters of the value of parameter starting at  the  character  specified  by  offset.   **If parameter  is `@`, an indexed array subscripted by `@` or `*`, or an associative array name, the results differ as described below.** If length is               omitted, expands to the substring of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset and extending to the end  of  the
> value.  length and offset are arithmetic expressions (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION below).
> **If parameter is `@`, the result is `length` positional parameters beginning at `offset`**. If parameter is an indexed array name subscripted by `@` or `*`, the result is the length members of the array beginning with `${parameter[offset]}`.

> Substring indexing is zero-based unless the positional parameters are used, in which case the indexing starts at 1 by default.  **If `offset` is 0, and the positional parameters are used, `$0` is prefixed to the list**.

So if you use:

```
"${@:0}"
```

That will also include `$0`

however as mentioned earlier:

```
"$@"
```

will start from position one.

PS: Note that in previous `bash` versions, behavior is different and `"${@:0}"` won't include `$0`.

Comment: The manual only says that `${parameter:offset:length}` is for extracting a substring, not a sub-array.

Comment: @Thomas: Please read next sentences. It has a special subsection for arrays and `@`

Comment: @anubhava Indeed, thanks. Your answer would be more complete if you quoted that bit too :) That part even sort-of suggests that `${@:offset:length}` is special syntax completely separate from `$@` itself.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, I have added more relevant sections of `man bash` to make it more clear. @actual_panda as you can see this is specified behavior as per man page.

Comment: Where exactly does it say `$0` is a positional parameter? Although it makes total sense that `${@:0}` expands to `$0 $1 ...`, it doesn't seem to be actually documented. ZSH behaves the same way, and its manual says that is for compatibility with other shells (ksh93 and bash).

Comment: It is not undocumented. This section implies the behavior `If length is omitted, expands to the substring of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset `. So when `offset` is `0` it will expand to `$0 $1 $2...`

Comment: @oguzismail: Thanks so much your edit and for adding more relevant section of `man` page in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Am I the only one that finds the documentation hilariously confusing? If the behavior is that hard to explain, it's probably not a good idea. I barely got what they are talking about thanks to you highlighting the important parts.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what Ksh and Zsh also do (and the substring/array slice notation is likely to originate from Ksh).

The point of `$@` only giving the positional parameters and not `$0`, is that it can be used in loops like `for x in "$@"; do ...` (though you could just use `for x do ...`) or passed to other commands, as in `somecmd "$@"`, possibly after some shifting to modify the list. Mixing `$0` in the same list is very rarely useful.

But in `${@:0:n}`, you explicitly ask for index `0`, too.
There's really no reason *not* to give the user the possibility of including `$0`, since if they don't want it, they could use `$@` or `${@:1}` instead.

With regular arrays, `${array[0]}` is a regular element, so is naturally included in both `${array[@]}` and `${array[@]:0}`.